# C# synchronous TCP client socket unexplained missing data

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-3.0, tcpclient

I'm using TCP over an unreliable mobile data connection, which may drop packets due to interference or whatever may be going wrong with the signal strength.

What complicates matters is that I'm using Modbus TCP and the mobile router on the other end converts this into Modbus RTU (Serial) in order to communicate with a serial based device (slave).

Furthermore, whenever a read request is sent to the serial device its internal pointer will be incremented to the next chunk of data as soon as the response has been sent. The serial device will have no idea whether the mobile connection is still OK; if the response does not make it all the way back to the server it will already have incremented its internal pointer anyway.

In other words take the following scenario:

1. Server sends modbus read request over TCP.
2. Router receives request and passes it to serial device.
3. Serial device responds to router.
4. Serial device increments data pointer.
5. Router fails to send TCP packet back to server.
6. Server sends read request again.
7. Serial device responds to router.
8. Serial device increments data pointer.
9. Router send data back to server successfully.

In the above scenario you will see that the problem in step 5 causes a whole data chunk to be missed, because the serial device has no idea that the previous read operation actually failed. It has already moved on to the next chunk! Normally what I would do is detect this problem and use the "request previous data chunk" operation to re-request the previously missed data chunk from the serial device.

Here is my problem: I'm not getting any exceptions or errors from the TCP code even though I have everything enclosed in a SystemException try-catch block and I'm checking the return value.

I looked through my log file carefully and noticed that the time between a request and a response is about 1 second, however at the time of the suspected missed data chunk, the time gap was between 2 and 3 seconds. This would suggest that a send occured, but no data was received so it tried again. But of course when it tried again, the serial device would have already incremented its data pointer to the next set of data.

For some reason the serial device received the read request, however the data never made it back to the server.

I'm not an expert on TCP/IP, so does anyone out there know what could have happened? Is it possible for TCP to resend packets "under the hood" without causing exceptions and without me knowing?

In my code I'm simply doing something like this:

```
_log.Debug(string.Format("[{0}]: Sending sync response ({1}).", 
    this._IP.ToString(), CoreUtils.PayloadToString(write_data)));

tcpSynCl.Send(write_data, 0, write_data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
int result = tcpSynCl.Receive(tcpSynClBuffer, 0, 
               tcpSynClBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

byte function = tcpSynClBuffer[7];
byte[] data;    

if (result == 0) throw SystemException("No data received");

// ... process log buffer ...

_log.Debug(string.Format("[{0}]: Got sync response ({1}).", 
    this._IP.ToString(), CoreUtils.PayloadToString(data)));

return data;
```

There were no exceptions thrown, which would suggest that something happened between Send() and Receive() under the hood. The time between the two debug log entries was twice as long than all the others. Possible or not possible?

Comment: How do you delimit messages? Do you use a zero byte? It kinds of looks like you forgot to implement a protocol. If you want to send messages over TCP, you have to use some kind of protocol that defines what a message *is*. I bet if you log the total number of bytes sent and the total number received, they will be equal, showing that the bug is in your code failing to identify the messages correctly.

Comment: Haven't heard of any packet loss issues due to C# unless there is network connectivity issues.

  If I assume your connectivity is not a problem, do you write both Server and Router in C# by yourself?  If so why don't you replace one end at the server to some proven server programs like http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/ and try again? 

  The above test will help you isolate the issue.

Comment: David: The protocol works fine as I have tested it thoroughly using a direct LAN connection and also serial connection.

Comment: Muthu: The mobile (HSUPA) router is an off the shelf product. It takes a TCP modbus packet on a given port (say 502) strips any TCP headers off it and then puts the payload into a ModbusRTU structure and sends it via the onboard serial port. It then takes the reply and sends it back as ModbusTCP. The problem I'm having occurs randomly, but on average about once every 2 days. Transfers last about 1-2 minutes every 30 minutes. Due to the randomness I believe it is a connection issue (e.g. random interference) however I don't seem to be getting an exception from the underlying Socket object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Receiving 0 bytes do not mean that you haven't received anything. It means that the connection has been closed.

Second: It's likely that you'll receive two messages at the same time due to Nagle algorithm. You need to go through the received bytes and see how messages there are in there. TCP is not message based but stream based.

Comment: Thanks jgauffin. Since I'm using synchronous sockets and the serial device produces exactly one response for every request I don't see how it's possible to have two messages. My code does not ask the serial device for the next message until the previous method has returned. Also, any received data gets inserted into a byte list as a hex string until I get a "no more data" response. The data is then merged and post-processed. Even if I receive multiple messages it would all get merged. However, as I said I log the entire buffer each time I get a message and the missing data never showed up.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of TCP is to make the stream transparent to the application. Lost packets are handled by TCP and not the application. If TCP does not get an ACK for a given packet, it will  attempt to resend the packet. It will eventually stop sending any other packets and continue to resend that lost packet until it receives and ACK or the connection times out.

Similar on the receiving side. If a packet is lost, the TCP stack will not send any data to the application until it receives the missing packet. TCP also guarantees packet order. A lost packet will cause the receiver to stop until it either gets the missing packet or times out.

The receiver will accept and buffer some of the packets that came after the dropped packet and "play them back" once the missing packet is received.